# Move a file from eight days ago

Tags: powershell

I want to move a file from eight days ago:

```
[int]$EightDaysAgo = -8

$weeklyFile = Get-ChildItem $SourceFolder -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -eq (Get- 
Date).AddDays($EightDaysAgo)} 
Move-Item $weeklyFile -Destination $DestinationFolder -Force
```

I am not getting anything returned for $weeklyFile but when I change the -eq to lt I get files returned.
In my source folder I have a file for the last 21 days and I want to move the file from 8 days ago.

Any idea what I am doing wrong??

Comment: Did you try to remove the `Where-Object` and see what files are shown? Then you can check whether there is a file from 8 days ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[datetime]` also includes the time of day, which may differ between now and the time of day when the file was written to.

You can "reset" the daily clock on a `[datetime]` instance by referencing the `Date` property:

```bsh
$EightDaysAgo = (Get-Date).AddDays(-8).Date

$weeklyFile = Get-ChildItem $SourceFolder -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime.Date -eq $EightDaysAgo}
```